# Scrolled content height using jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll

Overflow is set to auto for a div. How can I get the height of div portion that is scrolled upward and is not visible now using jQuery. Also how can I get height of only visible portion of div.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

        // calculate the percentage the user has scrolled down the page
        var scrollwin = $(window).scrollTop();
        var scrollArticle = $('.main').scrollTop();
        var articleheight = $('.main').outerHeight(true);
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        if (scrollwin >= $('.main').offset().top) {
            if (scrollwin <= ($('.main').offset().top + articleheight)) {
//I want this percentage to be calculated on current visible portion of div plus above scrolled portion that is not visible. ScrollArticle is giving 0 value. 
                $('.bar-long').css('width', ((scrollArticle + $(window).height()) / articleheight) * 100 + "%");
            } else {
                $('.bar-long').css('width', "100%");
            }
        } else {
            $('.bar-long').css('width',( $(window).height() / articleheight) * 100 + "%");
        }


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `scrollTop()` property of the element; that's the height from the absolute top of the element to it's visible top.

Comment: I tried $('.idOfDiv').scrollTop(). This is giving 0 value.

Comment: If you want in depth help you will need to edit your question to include your code. I can't help you without seeing what you have